# Java. Откуда лишние разряды в выводе?

Tags: java

Не пойму, в чем причина появления кучи разрядов в выводе.
при float появляются девятки вместо нулей.
*код:*

```
class sol_3_2{
    static double f(double x) {
        if (x > 2) return x;
        else return -x;
    }
    
    public static void z(double a, double b, double h) {
        System.out.println("x\t" + "f(x)\t");
        for (double x = a; x <= b; x += h) {
            System.out.println(x + "\t" + f(x) );
        }
    }
}

public class ex_3_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 4;
        double b = 10;
        double h = 0.7;
        sol_3_2.z(a, b, h);
    }
}
```

*вывод:*

[image: консоль]

Comment: https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Answer (score 0):

Используйте форматированный вывод с точностью до 1 знака после десятичной точки `%5.1f`:

```java
System.out.printf("   x\t  f(x)%n");
for (double x = a; x <= b; x += h) {
    System.out.printf("%5.1f\t%5.1f%n", x, f(x));
}
```

```
   x      f(x)
  4.0     4.0
  4.7     4.7
  5.4     5.4
  6.1     6.1
  6.8     6.8
  7.5     7.5
  8.2     8.2
  8.9     8.9
  9.6     9.6
```